# Will Twin Throw feat work with Empowered Shot Feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics, ranged-attack

Twin Throw states

> making a full-attack action with a thrown weapon, your first attack fires two thrown weapons.

and Empowered Shot says

> You may expend your psionic focus as part of a ranged attack (but not ranged touch attack) to ignore any penalties for range increment for that single attack.

Does this mean even if you full attack, only make a single attack in that that full attack action and use you psionic focus, both thrown weapons' range is still at its maximum range at no penalties?

Is this true:

Shuriken 1d2 TR: 19x2 Range: 10 feet

- 1 Shuriken with Empowered Shot 20 feet
- 1 Shuriken with ES and Psi Focus used 100 feet no pen
- 2 Shuriken with ES and Twin Throw both at 20 feet
- 2 Shuriken with ES, TT and Psi focus used both at 100 feet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct, so if we imagine you have three attacks, Twin Throw, Empowered shot, and that you are focused

full attack action with focus spent:
You first attack has it's range doubled and no penalty whatsoever, but as you loose your focus, all the subsequent attacks halve their range increment

- **primary** 2 Shurikens, focus used, Max distance 100 feet (at no penalty)
- **secondary** 1 Shuriken - RI 10 feet - Max distance 50 feet (at -10)
- **third** 1 Shuriken - RI 10 feet - Max distance 50 feet (at -10)

full attack action while focused:
The bonus of being focused applies to all attacks and effectively doubles range increment

- **primary** 2 Shurikens, twin throw, RI 20 feet - Max distance 100feet (at -10)
- **secondary** 1 Shuriken - RI 20 feet - Max distance 100 feet (at -10)
- **third** 1 Shuriken - RI 20 feet - Max distance 100 feet (at -10)

*Remember that when you send two shuriken at once with TT, you only make one attack roll.*

Comment: OK that good to now but what if you do have 3 attacks and  use TT as a full attack action use only of three attacks and fore go rest of you attacks. Is TT still applicable or do you literally have to make all the attacks to have the feat work.

Comment: Twin throws needs you to make a **full attack action** to activate. 
The full attack action is a **full-round action** that takes all your actions of the turn except your swift action,  your free actions and your ability to make a five-foot step.

So you can choose to voluntarily miss your remaining attacks, but that would be pure waste and wouldn't allow you to take a move action. If you want to move after an attack, you must do an **attack action** so that you have a move action still available,  and Twin throw doesn't activate.